# Handling password input with shell-command or vc-git-push for ssh keys

Tags: vc, passwords

I'm trying to automate pushing to a git remote, let's say with code that looks like this:

```
(defun my-git-push (repo)
  (let ((default-directory repo))
    (vc-git-push nil)))
```

I get this error: `ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/lib64/misc/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory`

Is there a way for vc-git to handle password input instead? Similarly to magit/tramp.

Also, when using something like `shell-command "git push"` I'm not prompted for password input.

How would you implement a function that would run like a hook to push changes to a remote repo & prompt for password input on the mini buffer, using only built-in `emacs-29.2` functions

Comment: "when using something like shell-command "git push" I'm not prompted for password input" -- that suggests that your shell config may be setting things up in your environment to enable the behaviour you want.  Are you starting Emacs from a shell?  If not, doing so should be an easy way to test what happens when Emacs inherits it's environment from whatever you shell configures.

Comment: @phils I'm starting Emacs using rofi, from Gentoo if that matters, but I can replicate this issue when starting emacs from bash just fine. I can't find any $SSH variables set on my shell, I installed =x11-ssh-askpass= for now. From my understanding, packages like magit use a `set-process-filter` to filter for password input (from a quick look on magit-process.el) What's the behavior of your setup when using vc-push? Is it just me? I could replicate this on my Arch machine as well. NOTE: I'm prompted for password input when using async-shell-command or just eshell/bash

Comment: An example that I found might work with start-process-shell-command is using a filter like this: ```(set-process-filter proc (lambda (proc string)
-          (when (string-match "Password\\|password\\|passphrase" string)
-     (process-send-string proc (read-passwd "Password: ")))))``` but it doesn't always work for some reason and it's not as a sophisticated solution as one might expect. I thought vc could manage something like that.

Comment: FWIW I'd be looking for ssh-agent or gpg-agent usage first and foremost.  I haven't looked, but I wouldn't *expect* `vc-git-push` to invoke a shell, so it still sounds to me like something in your shell config is going to be the difference.  I'm only speculating, though.

Comment: @phils thanks for the input, but from a quick grep of vc, it uses shell-command & read-shell-command a lot actually, it even has `ssh-askpass` hardcoded on cvs-parse-ignored-messages.

Comment: My brief look suggests that `vc-do-command` calls either `start-file-process` or `process-file` depending on whether or not the command is to be executed asynchronously, so no shell there unless the program being called is a shell.  I suggest you use `trace-function` and *verify* what's being used.

Comment: trace-output of vc-push: 1 -> (vc-push nil)
| 2 -> (vc-git-push nil)
| 2 <- vc-git-push: #<process git>
1 <- vc-push: #<process git>
--- I can't find any filter or prompt for password input anywhere in vc

Comment: Ah, no, that doesn't help.  I meant trace `start-file-process` and `process-file` to confirm whether/which of those ends up being used (and if neither, then it's something else).  You could also use the debugger to step your way from `vc-push`.

Comment: Also, my comments are only focussing on the fact that you *don't* have a password prompt when using the shell, so I'm not trying to get you a password prompt; I'm only suggesting that confirming the difference between the shell and the non-shell cases is a step on the way to not having them in Emacs either.  (If for some reason you *want* to deal with password prompts, nothing I'm saying is really helpful.)

Comment: @phils this has actually been really fun rabbit hole, I will update this when I have a solid solution. Btw are you Philip that made compat? Thanks for the support either way :)

Comment: No, that's a different Philip :)  You're welcome, and I'm glad you're having fun with it!