vc-dir push : how to setup the gitconfig
I am using vc-dir for simple git tasks and I am happy with it but for the moment I still need to push outside of emacs and I would like to fix this. When I push (C-x v P), I get the following error: fatal: could not read Username for 'https://gitlab.com': No such device or address.
Can someone help me with setting right the gitconfig file for that? I tried several thing and it didn't work:

pushing with another package (magit) worked without problems, I was prompted to enter my username and password.

I tried to enter in my gitconfig the name of my user in gitlab but this didn't help.

pushing manually worked. I am prompted to enter my username with the following input sentence: Username for 'https://gitlab.com': so it seems that vc doesn't understand that it's a prompt to enter the username.

I added (setq vc-command-messages t) to my .emacs  and got the additional message when I push: Done in background: git --no-pager ls-files -z -o --exclude-standard -- .



That's an error from git push I believe and it has nothing to do with Emacs. Please ask the question in a git-related forum (maybe https://unix.stackexchange.com/), and add all relevant details (including what you tried that did not work).

That's related to vc-dir because I managed to push using magit. so this is why I am asking for vc-dir.

Provide details of what you did with each then (and also doing git push from the command line without either magit or vc involved). In particular, your setup with gitlab.com is probably relevant. Add everything to your question: do not reply with a comment. The question needs to stand on its own.

Thanks for the extra information. I believe the question is now clear and relevant to the Emacs SE.

Try customizing vc-command-messages to t, repeat the command, and add all the messages to your question. It might be easiest to cut-and-paste from the *Messages* buffer.

If vc is running the git commands asynchronously in the background, that would explain why it can't deal with prompts. Perhaps you can arrange for git to be able to login without prompting. E.g. if it uses ssh to get to gitlab, you can use ssh-agent. But note that that is not an Emacs question, so we're back where we started,

Maybe related: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/80408/handling-password-input-with-shell-command-or-vc-git-push-for-ssh-keys
